# attach library inside formElement in custom field widget

Tags: drupal-8

Hello everyone i am stuck in a place, I have created a custom field type and field widget and inside my field widget i have to call the js as image choose button is selected. Here is my code for custom field widget

```
public function formElement(
FieldItemListInterface $items,
$delta,
Array $element,
Array &$form,
FormStateInterface $formState
) {
$s3FormDetailss = GetSignature::getSignature();// To get the policy

$element['s3_select_image'] = array(
 '#type' => 'managed_file',
 '#title' => t($element['#title']),
 '#description' => t('Upload to s3'),
 '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->s3_upload_bucket_name) ?
     $items[$delta]->s3_upload_bucket_name: null,
 $form['#attached']['#library'][]= 's3_file_uploader/s3_file_uploader-s3_file_uploader-styles',
 $form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['s3_file_uploader']['s3_file_uploader-s3_file_uploader-styles']['variable'] = $s3FormDetailss,

);
```

I want to attach the library here but i am getting error 
"You are not allowed to use #library in #attached."

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the # sign:
`$form['#attached']['library'][]= '';`